# What does "scope updated from test" mean in Maven?

Tags: maven

I have a test dependency "foo" that has a transitive dependency "bar". In addition, I have "bar" as a compile time dependency somewhere else in my pom. I noticed when I run mvn dependency:tree, it states that the transitive test dependency "bar" is "compile - scope updated from test; omitted for duplicate".

What is happening here? Is maven intelligent enough to know that "bar" requires the compile scope? If so, this is great. I just want to confirm this behaviour as a good search doesn't seem to help me here.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Transitive Dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) are resolved , bar is resolved
to compile scope, but omitted as it is already resolved.

You can test yourself by having different version of "bar" for "foo". It always uses version of "bar" your project directly dependence because of nearest definition in dependency tree

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the most common situation I have run into is when a transitive dependency of a test dependency is also a transitive dependency of a compile dependency. This can also occur if the transitive dependency of a test dependency is also a direct compile dependency. Since such a dependency is needed as, or to satisfy, a compile dependency, it is updated from test to compile.

This case can be seen clearly using the command `mvn -Dverbose dependency:tree`.